# How to bind functions in let evaluating them later

Tags: clojure, quil

I'm learning Clojure to use it with Quil to make generative art and I would like to try to understand a bit more about let function and reader macro probably.

I tried reading about reader macros from the docs but I couldn't find a clear answer to it.

I currently have this piece of code:

```
(let [dabs (take 10 (repeatedly #(make-watercolor 
                                   (mkpt 
                                     (randomNormal 0.1 0.9) 
                                     (randomNormal 0.1 0.9))
                                   (w (randomNormal 0.4 0.7)))))]
    (draw-multiple-watercolor dabs 3))
```

Which is pretty ugly and not really readable.
I would like to slim down the repeated function splitting it into smaller pieces, but since those pieces will be evaluated multiple times and has random inside them I cannot store their result inside a variable and use that, instead I need to evaluate those when needed.

My question is: is there a way to do something like this

```
(let [randCoord (randomNormal 0.1 0.9) ;This..
      randPoint (mkpt randCoord randCoord) ;..and this doesn't should be evaluated here, but on the repeatedly function calls
      dabs (take 10 (repeatedly #(make-watercolor 
                                   randPoint ;Evaluation here
                                   (w (randomNormal 0.4 0.7)))))]
    (draw-multiple-watercolor dabs 3))
```

Comment: Do you consider `(let [make-wc-fn #(make-watercolor ...), dabs (take 10 (repeatedly make-wc-fn))] ...)` ugly? I'd argue that it's the nesting, not the use of an anonymous function, that makes the code a mess. Give that function its own name, and it's no longer being defined somewhere that's deeply nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the same approach you've used with the function you pass to `repeatedly`: just wrap the expressions in functions that take no arguments (or only the args you want to change), then they'll be evaluated each time you invoke the function.

```
(let [rand-coord (fn [] (randomNormal 0.1 0.9)) ;; or #(randomNormal 0.1 0.9)
      make-dab #(make-watercolor (mkpt (rand-coord) (rand-coord))
                                 (w (randomNormal 0.4 0.7)))
      dabs (take 10 (repeatedly make-dab))]
  (draw-multiple-watercolor dabs 3))
```

Also take a look at `letfn` for defining functions in a non-top-level/namespace scope.

You might also find *threading* macros like `->`, `->>`, `as->`, `some->`, `cond->`, etc. can make some code more readable. For example, if you changed `draw-multiple-watercolor` to take its sequence of dabs *last* (which is fairly common practice for functions that operate on sequences in Clojure) then you could do something like this:

```
(let [rand-coord (fn [] (randomNormal 0.1 0.9)) ;; or #(randomNormal 0.1 0.9)
      make-dab #(make-watercolor (mkpt (rand-coord) (rand-coord))
                                 (w (randomNormal 0.4 0.7)))]
  (->> make-dab
       (repeatedly 10) ;; note: repeatedly can take a # of iterations
       (draw-multiple-watercolor 3)))
```

Comment: I remember i tried the #() macro like your comment says but I didn't managed to make it work with the random thing, I'll try it again later and let you know. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I just tried and it worked! I wasn't using the binded function with the () so it was warking before but not with a correct use of random giving me always the same results. Now it works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @elkiwy nice, I also got into Quil for visualizing some Advent of Code problems [here](https://github.com/taylorwood/advent-of-code#2018). Have fun!